# UAF Exploitation Tips

Tags: use-after-free

I am trying to exploit a use-after-free that was previously patched for practice/to get good :) I am trying to bypass ALSR and get code execution in the process.

The program allocates an object in the scope of a function, then frees it (overwrites most of its values with a5s). There is a JS callback, and once that completes a virtual method is called from the object.

I can spray the heap with JS objects to get one on top of the freed object during the callback (and I can spray the heap with shellcode/NOP sled). I cannot access the original object reference from JS. Any ideas?

Comment: To bypass aslr you generally need an additional bug, that can be used as an infoleak which then lets you calculate offset addresses from a base address.